# Readonly semantics

Tags: c#

I have a class called **ArrayType** and **ListType** which both implement these fields:

```
public readonly Type underlyingType;
public readonly bool isUnderlyingTypeComplex;
```

Somewhere along my implementation i need to access those fields in either ArrayType or ListType, so i created a base class called **UnderlyingType**:

```
abstract class UnderlyingType
{
        public readonly Type underlyingType;
        public readonly bool isUnderlyingTypeComplex;
}
```

Problem is i need to implement both fields in the base class constructor and i cant do it in the derived class. One solution its just checking the derived class type and implement it like this:

```
public UnderlyingType()
{
    if (this.GetType() == typeof(ArrayType))
    {
        underlyingType = workingType.GetElementType();
        isUnderlyingTypeComplex = FXS_Utils.IsComplexType(underlyingType);
    }
    else
    {
        underlyingType = workingType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        isUnderlyingTypeComplex = FXS_Utils.IsComplexType(underlyingType);
    }
}
```

But this defeat readability at least for me... also interfaces cant have fields, so how do i implement readonly fields in this case?.

Also, why i dont choose a readonly property?. Well cause i want to explicitly tell whoever is reading my source, that those fields will never change after construction. Its a thing about semantics, more than anything...

Comment: Don't use a field: public Type underlyingType { get; protected set; }

Comment: Is it that important to your clients that the "readonly" semantics are explicit? Standard practice when making an immutable object is to use properties.

Comment: This tells me that the property can be changed after construction, which is exactly why i wanted to use readonly field...

Comment: @Blorgbeard well more than anything just a curiosity question, i was wondering what solution (if there is one beside readonly properties) i have for this.

Comment: Well, there isn't one that I know of.

Comment: Its also killing me than most of my classes use readonly fields for the same reason (the semantics) and suddenly in those two i need to implement them as properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was my way of solving this the best i could:

```
internal interface IUnderlyingType
{
    Type underlyingType { get; }
    bool isUnderlyingTypeComplex { get; }
}
```

And in the **ArrayType** class for example:

```
    public readonly Type underlyingType;
    public readonly bool isUnderlyingTypeComplex;

    //Internal Interface implementation
    Type IUnderlyingType.underlyingType { get { return underlyingType; } }
    bool IUnderlyingType.isUnderlyingTypeComplex { get { return isUnderlyingTypeComplex; } }
```

This way i can keep the readonly fields for my clients and a internal interface for implementing this in other objects that use underlyingTypes, like **ListType**.